# String Mask in codeEval

Tags: python, python-3.x

https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/199/ here is description of  an exercise.

It's my solution for me is correct, but in codeEval I have status 'Partially'. Maybe someone know what is wrong ?

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test_cases:
for test in test_cases:

    a, b = test.split()

    for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if value == '1':
            a = a.replace(a[index], a[index].upper())

    print (a)

test_cases.close()
```

Comment: (i) Your indentation is screwed up, (ii) the `a = a.replace..` line is wrong (it will work for the input samples listed, but not for e.g. `hello 00010`)

Comment: I add to replace max argument `a.replace(a[index], a[index].upper(),1)` but i don't see what is wrong indentation

Comment: The for loop should be invented inside the with-statement.

Comment: Thanks, now I see. In my task on codeEval I have properly indentation. But  I have still the status 'Partially', what else could block solution ?

`import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as test_cases:
    for test in test_cases:

    a, b = test.split()

    for index, value in enumerate(b):
        if value == '1':
            a = a.replace(a[index], a[index].upper(), 1)

    print (a)

test_cases.close()`

Answer (score 0):

One big problem here is that when you need to uppercase a character based on its position in a string, you shouldn't be using replace, which in the way you are using it uppercases *all* occurrences of that character in the string, regardless of whether or not they are in positions that are supposed to be uppercased.